# How To Use Bucket Selector In Kibana Data Visulization?

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana

How can I use bucket_selector in the Data Table visulization?

I see there is an open request for this feature [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/17544). I'm wondering if there is a way for me to get around the lack of this feature for now. I'm open to using something very hacky.